# Issues with MOSFET in Water Atomizer Circuit

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm, inductor, boost

I'm currently facing an issue with my water atomizer setup, and I'm hoping to get some insights from the experts here. I have a circuit where I'm driving a water atomizer using an IRF3205 MOSFET and a 220uH inductor. The power is supplied through a boost circuit providing 24V.

Here are the key details of my setup:

- MOSFET: [IRF3205](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a)
- Inductor: 220uH
- PWM frequency: 109kHz
- Duty cycle: 80%

Atomizer power: 24V (from boost circuit)

While the mist density is satisfactory, I'm experiencing issues with the smoothness of operation. It appears that the mist is not coming out smoothly.

I've tried adjusting the PWM frequency and duty cycle, but the problem persists. Could anyone provide guidance on why this might be happening and suggest potential solutions?

[image: Circuit for water atomizer]

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you probed it with your scope and posted the result. What does the PWM look like at the MOSFET gate, before C1 and after C1 for example.

Comment: Pictures may help. Scope plot would definitely help. I would suspect that the boost converter isn't powerful enough. This circuit will draw huge current spikes. Did you try some big caps on the boost converter output?

Comment: You're not driving M1 correctly; the arduino can only output 3.3 V or 5 V (depending on model), while the IRF3205 is specified to be driven at 10 V on the gate. Figure 1 suggests that 5 V would be adequate, but remember that the figures are drawn from typical characteristics, not maxima. Vth can be as high as 4 V, so 3.3 V would definitely be inadequate, and I wouldn't rely on 5 V drive either.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a "10E" resistor? E is not a standard symbol that I've ever seen. Is it a 10 Ω resistor, which might sometimes be written as 10R?

Comment: Or is 10E the actual marking on the resistor, which probably means you read "301" upside down and it's a 300 Ω resistor?

Comment: What is the value and rated voltage for C1? There may be arcing inside the capacitor.